# does there exists a rope such that it takes longer to burn the whole rope from one end?

Tags: physical-chemistry

And it takes less time to burn from the other end.

The rope could be any of materials and structures and asymmetric.

EDIT:
But the external environment may not change during burning, and the way (eg positioning)to burn from both ends must be the same.

I am looking for properties of the rope to achieve this condition, eg. what if one end is smaller than the other end.

Comment: Sure: put a bottle of gasoline and a small explosive charge at one end.

Comment: @Carl If we assume that the rope's material is homogeneous (but of course not isotropic), then loopholes like that could be avoided and the question could be worth looking at.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft if there is an explosion, would the rope be consumed by oxidization (burning), or just blowed apart?

Comment: I think that, besides the obvious stuff, there _may_ be an answer that uses some kind of 'directional threading". That is, a way of weaving/braiding the rope that is asymmetrical in direction (but repeating).

Comment: cross-posted at: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/13571/

Comment: Something that has an internal structure like this perhaps: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_sinnet#mediaviewer/File:Chain-sinnet-ABOK-1144.jpg.

Comment: I closed the one on chemistry for the time being.  I think it's more appropriate here.

Answer (score 1):

If you hang a rope vertically, then lighting it from the bottom will make it burn more quickly than if you light it at the top... the key to answering this is "if the rope is symmetrical, I need to add asymmetry in the environment". And that is provided by gravity, and the effect it has on flames (hot air rising).

Comment: This is not necessarily true, and the false assumption that fire only (or preferentially) propagates upward is part of the reason Texas executed an innocent man.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - I am sorry to hear an innocent man was executed. There is much wrong with the "justice" system! Still - in an _otherwise unconstrained_ environment with normal gravity and no wind, the heat of a flame will cause it to point upwards - at which point it heats the rope above it, and will accelerate the time it takes to catch fire. I never said it is the only way that fire propagates - but I would gladly play a game with you where we light a match, and I hold it "up" and you hold it "down" (holding it still). First one to burn his fingers loses.